# Re-order Content Types for a List in code

Tags: object-model, content-type, list, development

Has anyone been able to re-order content types for a list in code?

If I'm given a specific content type, I want to make it the default in a list, by re-ordering the SPList.ContentTypes collection and setting my content type to position 0.

I've tried making a new collection (SPContentTypeCollection), setting the order in a loop and replacing the SPList.ContentTypes, but unfortunately that property is read-only.

The SPBaseCollection (which is inherited by SPContentTypeCollection) is pretty darned limited when it comes to collection operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I had to do this. But from memory, rather than playing with the SPContentTypeCollection on the SPList, you should modify the [`SPFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.uniquecontenttypeorder.aspx) property on the `SPList.RootFolder`.

Doing this will let you re-order the ContentTypes, and from memory you are correct about the item at index 0 being the Default.

Comment: Awesome, cheers! The UniqueContentTypeOrder is an IList which is nicer to play with. Why do all things with content types have so many aliases? :(

Comment: how can we do that with rest api ?